# How to monitor processes on linux

Tags: c++, c, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system

When an executable is running on Linux, it generates processes, threads, I/O ... etc, and uses libraries from languages like C/C++, sometimes there might be timers in question, is it possible to monitor this? how can I get a deep dive into these software and processes and what is going on in the background?

I know this stuff is abstracted from me because I shouldn't be worrying about it as a regular user, but I'm curious to what would I see.

What I need to see are:

1. System calls for this process/thread.
2. Open/closed sockets.
3. Memory management and utilization, what block is being accessed.
4. Memory instructions.
5. If a process is depending on the results of another one.
6. If a process/thread terminates, why, and was it successful?
7. I/O operations and DB read/write if any.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe in more detail what you mean with "monitor this". With `strace -f your_program` you can see the system calls of your program and its children. There are lots of options to specify what you want to see and how. See [`man strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: It is not fully clear for all points of your numbered list what exactly you mean, but most of these can be seen with `strace`. You can see dynamic memory allocation, but not the actual memory access. I didn't write this as an answer because this comment is only a hint, not detailed instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different things you wanted to *monitor* may require different tools. All tools I will mention below have extensive manual pages where you can find exactly how to use them.

> System calls for this process/thread.

The **strace** command does exactly this - it lists exactly which system calls are invoked by your program. The **ltrace** tool is similar, but focuses on calls to library functions -  not just system calls (which involve the kernel).

> Open/closed sockets.

The strace/ltrace commands will list among other things socket creation, but if you want to know which sockets are open - connected, listening, and so on - right now, there is the **netstat** utility, which lists all the connected (or with "-a", also listening) sockets in the system, and which process they belong to.

> Memory management and utilization, what block is being accessed.
> Memory instructions.

Again ltrace will let you see all malloc()/free() calls, but to see exactly what memory is being access where, you'll need a debugger, like **gdb**. The thing is that almost everything your program does will be a "memory instruction" so you'll need to know exactly what you are looking for, with breakpoints, tracepoints, single-stepping, and so on, and usually don't just want to see every memory access in your program.

If you don't want to find all memory accesses but rather are searching for *bugs* in this area - like accessing memory after it's freed and so on, there are tools that help you find those more easily. One of them called **ASAN** ("Address Sanitizer") is built into the C++ compiler, so you can build with it enabled and get messages on bad access patterns. Another one you can use is **valgrind**.

Finally, if by "memory utilization" you meant to just check how much memory your process or thread is using, well, both **ps** and **top** can tell you that.

> If a process is depending on the results of another one.
> If a process/thread terminates, why, and was it successful?

Various tools I mentioned like strace/ltrace will let you know when the process they follow exits. Any process can print the exit code of one of its sub-processes, but I'm not aware of a tool which can print the exit status of all processes in the system.

> I/O operations

There is **iostat** that can give you periodic summaries of how much IO was done to each disk. **netstat -s** gives you network statistics so you can see how many network operations were done. **vmstat** gives you, among other things, statistics on IO caused by swap in/out (in case this is a problem in your case).

> and DB read/write if any.

This depends on your DB, I guess, and how you monitor it.